# How can I fully fill the parent div with its child elements?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a div called `#menu` which is 800px wide. Inside of it, I have 8 navigation links. The elements in it should be as long as possible and should all be of the same width, but they should, together, fill the parent div on a single row (i.e. without wrapping).

Between each element, there should be a 1px border (or perhaps a 1px side-margin). All links, except the current page link (whichever link `#current` is applied to) should have a `1px solid #505050` bottom border. While the current page link should **not** have a visible bottom border (so that the navigation tab "merges" with the content div).

My current code does almost what I want already, but it's missing the border/margin between the links... If I add borders/margins to the sides, obviously, the current `12.5%` width (see CSS code below) becomes inaccurate, and I can't fine-tune it so that it does fill the `#menu` div **cross-browser** (either the elements will overflow the `#menu` div, or they won't fill it - in at least one browser).

CSS:

```
#menu {
  border:1px solid #505050;
  border-bottom:none;
  width:800px;
}

#menu a {
  display:inline-block;
  outline:none;
  text-align:center;
  width:12.5%;
  padding-top:12px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  background-image:url(/img/menu.gif);
  border-bottom:1px solid #505050;
  color:#D9D9D9;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-shadow:1px 1px #505050;
}

#menu #current {
  background-image:url(/img/menu_current.gif);
  color:#505050 !important;
  border-bottom-color:#D9D9D9;
  text-shadow:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="/page1.html" id="current">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/page2.html">Link 2</a>
    <a href="/page3.html">Link 3</a>
    <a href="/page4.html">Link 4</a>
    <a href="/page5.html">Link 5</a>
    <a href="/page6.html">Link 6</a>
    <a href="/page7.html">Link 7</a>
    <a href="/page8.html">Link 8</a>
  </div>
```

Two requirements:

- The solution should work in IE6 and later IE versions, as well as recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera
- No use of JavaScript, please

It's a big plus if:

- The solution works so that links can be added without having to re-adjust the width for the elements

You may of course rewrite the CSS/HTML completely. No need to re-use any of the code above, I'm just showing my own approach. Also, I am aware that the text-shadow rule isn't supported in IE6, but it isn't a requirement.

How it currently looks
[image: How it currently looks]

The expected result
[image: The expected result]

Answer (score 0):

hi i think u want to this  ***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/wyR4B8kr)***

add some `css` in you **stylesheet** as like this

```
#menu{
font-size:0;
}
#menu a {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#menu a + a{
border-left:solid 2px black;  // depent your design .
}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/wyR4B8kr)***

**Change color** or **border** according your design .

Comment: The borders doesn't show in IE6 unfortunately. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a html table instead of divs.

> #menu {
>       width:800px;
>       border-collapse:collapse;
>   }
>
> #menu td.other {
>     border:1px solid black;
>   }
>   td a {
>       display:inline-block;
>       outline:none;
>       text-align:center;
>       width:100%;
>       padding-top:12px;
>       padding-bottom:10px;
>       background-image:url(/img/menu.gif);
>       color:#D9D9D9;
>       font-weight:bold;
>       font-size:13px;
>       font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
>       text-shadow:1px 1px #505050;
>   }
>   #menu#current {
>       background-image:url(/img/menu_current.gif);
>       color:#505050 !important;
>       border-bottom-color:#D9D9D9;
>       text-shadow:none;
>       border-left:1px solid black;
>       border-right:1px solid black;
>       border-top:1px solid black;
>       border-bottom:1px solid #D9D9D9;
>   }

```
<table id="menu" border="0">
<tr>
    <td id="current"><a href="/page1.html">Link 1</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page2.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page3.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page4.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page5.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page6.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page7.html">Link 2</a></td>
    <td class="other"><a href="/page8.html">Link 2</a></td>
</tr>
```